# Search for pages created by user with Confluence REST API

Tags: confluence-rest-api

I want to get all pages created by a specific user via the REST API.

I tried the following REST call, but as result, I just get all pages on the homepage of Confluence, although I want to search the whole Confluence DB.

```
https://confluence/rest/api/content/search?cql=type=page&creator=currentUser()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cql` param must conform valid CQL. So instead of `&` use `AND`.

Example:

- Valid CQL: `type=page AND creator=currentUser()`
- Valid Request: `https://confluence.yourdomain.com/rest/api/content/search?cql=type%3Dpage%20AND%20creator%3DcurrentUser()`

Also make sure you (or the account requesting data) have access to all space on the Confluence instance (not only to a single space/homepage).

CQL documentation might be helpful too:

- Server: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/advanced-searching-using-cql/
- Cloud: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/advanced-searching-using-cql/